# Creating an icon with Users Initials

Tags: k2

I am trying to create logos for my system similar to the ones that are created on MS teams. Basically, each users Initials are made into a picture and is displayed throughout the system when referring to that user, instead of showing the users full name. it is also used as the users profile picture. Please note that my system is a K2 developed system

[Microsoft teams example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpoG0.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I found a post that explains how to do what i needed fairly well, if anybody was also trying to accomplish this

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-default-profile-image-dynamically-from-first-and-last/